# Assigning Different Colors to a Plot / Scatter

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, scatter

So I have a vector called `C1_Vector` that has been previously filled with different shades of 1 RGB color `([0 0.5 1])`, blue. So there are many different vectors within the `C1_Vector`

ex:

```
C1_Vector = ([0 0.5 1], [0 0.45 0.98], [0 0.49 1.01], etc.)
```

I want to each one of my points, in `s1`, to correspond to a different color. This is what I've been playing around with, and struggling with. Can someone help me with this syntax?

```
plot(s1(1,:),s1(2,:),'.', 'color', C1_Vector );
```

where,

```
s1 =

3.0000    3.0000    3.0000    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000         0   -1.5000
1.5000         0   -1.5000    1.5000         0   -1.5000         0    3.0000
```

Comment: This is in matlab, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [scatter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) function makes it quite easy as long as you provide the same number of color vectors than element to plot.

Basically for each pair of points to display the function assign it the corresponding color in the color matrix provided, which is `M x 3` where `M` is the number of points.

Therefore for the demo I added colors to `C1_Vector` so that it contains as many elements as `s1`.

```
C1_Vector = [0 0.5 1; 0 0.45 0.98; 0 0.49 1.01;1 0 1; rand(1,3); 0 1 0; 0 1 1;rand(1,3)];

s1 = [3.0000    3.0000    3.0000    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000         0 -1.5000;
1.5000         0   -1.5000    1.5000         0   -1.5000         0    3.0000];

scatter(s1(1,:),s1(2,:),[],C1_Vector,'filled')
grid on
```

Output:

[image]

Is that what you meant?